# Matplotlib minor ticks disable

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

In a figure that I already made that figure becomes like this

[image: Old]

the numbers in the x axes represents the weeks so this is every Thursdays in the week

I want to put the dates instead of the numbers and I worked on it more than 2 hours and get this figure:

[image: New]

but the lines are too thin and I think it is because of the minor ticks

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt;

from adjustText import adjust_text
plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


SaleF = open("Total Thu.txt", "r")
SalesSS1 = SaleF.read().split('\n')
SaleF.close()
if SalesSS1[-1] == "":
    del SalesSS1[-1]
SalesSS1 = list(map(int, SalesSS1))

objects = range(len(SalesSS1))
y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))

performance = SalesSS1

f8 = plt.figure()
plt.bar(y_pos, performance, align='center', alpha=0.5)
plt.xticks(y_pos, objects[::-1])
plt.ylabel('Sales Per Branch', fontsize=15)
plt.title(yesterday1.strftime('%A')+"s", fontsize=15)
plltSS = plt.gcf()
plltSS.set_size_inches(18,5)
plt.tight_layout()



for i in range(len(SalesSS1)):
    texts = [plt.text(objects[i], SalesSS1[i], f"{int(SalesSS1[i]):,d}",fontsize=6)]
    adjust_text(texts, autoalign='',only_move={'points':'', 'text':''})

plt.savefig('Day.png',dpi=150)
```

thank you

Comment: The "thickness of the lines" is the bar `width`. The units of the axis are days. So for example to have the bars be 5 days wide, use `bar(..., width=5)`.

Comment: thank you very much  I didnt thought that it is that easy  worked perfectly